# MySQL set No Null for all columns

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to set all columns as "NOT NULL" in my table? On my gameserver i have lots of tables and oclumns with "null" and i need them "not null". Can you help me? I was thinking this will help me

```
UPDATE player SET * = NOT NULL;
```

but it wont work.

Comment: you can get the columns tables from SCHEMA table and then you can set modify them all programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
      ALTER TABLE player  MODIFY your_column INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

If `Int` do `Int` If `Varchar` do `varchar` and so on

Comment: Note that this will have the effect of setting column values currently `NULL` to zero on a numeric column and an empty string on a VARCHAR column. Your data will be _changed_.

Comment: @echo_Me it wont work. `ALTER TABLE player_deleted  MODIFY * NOT NULL;` i want to set it for all columns and not all of them are INT

Comment: As I said. Not all Int . If varchar do varchar as I described

Comment: @echo_Me yes i know but i still cant do

ALTER TABLE player  MODIFY `*` INT(11) NOT NULL;

Comment: @user3572025 When its varchar, make it ...varchar... instead of ...int.... Start using your brain please.